# retrieve tf transform

Tags: ros, c++, state, robot, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow,

I'm trying to obtain information from the a tf transform. I've loaded my URDF file in the parameter server and run robot and joint state publish. Here is a picture of some links :

[image: Frames]

So I can see that the transform between /base_link and /camera is publish.

Now here is my code which is very simple as it is a test :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf_listener");

ros::NodeHandle node;
tf::TransformListener listener(ros::Duration(10));



tf::StampedTransform transform;
try{
    geometry_msgs::PointStamped base_point;

    listener.lookupTransform("/camera", "/base_link", ros::Time(0), transform);
}
catch(tf::TransformException& ex){
    ROS_ERROR("Received an exception trying to transform a point from \"camera\" to \"base_link\": %s", ex.what());
}

};
```

I'm just trying to have the transformation between /camera and /base_link. But I run in that error :

```
 rosrun tobot_goal listen 
[ERROR] [1396346328.110845542]: Received an exception trying to transform a point from "camera" to "base_link": Frame id /camera does not exist! Frames (1):
```

which would tend to mean that /camera is not publish. And if I try with any other frame I have, the result is the same...

Why can't I seem to not access those transformations ?

Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146826/retrieve-tf-transform/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess this is a timing issue, since you set up the tf listener and the immediately look up the transform, no tf data will have been received yet.

Try to use waitForTransform before the first lookup.

Also, you are not spinning, but IIRC the transform listener has its own threaded message queue for the tf topic, so that should be ok in this case.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-04-01**:
Thanks a lot ! Adding waitForTransform for the thing to do.